# How to return two values in Java

Tags: java, variables, return, limit, return-value

I know that java can't normally return two values, but I'm trying to return the value as a method.. From there I want to use the values of score1 and maxScore1 in a string in the main method. getHwGrades is the method I'm having issues with. I get "error: cannot find symbol". I'm not allowed to use arrays for this program. On another note, I'm also not supposed to use any if/else statements, but I could not find any other way to limit the value of discussionGrade to 20. Any help is appreciated

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Grades
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
Scanner getG = new Scanner(System.in);

int weight1;
int weight2;
int weight3;
int score2 = 0;
int maxScore2 = 0;
int sections;
int discussionGrade;






System.out.println("What is the weight for the HW and Exam 1?");
weight1 = getG.nextInt();
weight2 = getG.nextInt();
weight3 = getWeight(weight1, weight2);
System.out.println("Using weights of " + weight1 + " " + weight2 + " " + weight3);


 getHwGrades();
 sections = numberSections();
 discussionGrade = calcDGrade(sections);

System.out.println("What is your grade for exam1?"); //move under hw total points and final grade, add curve
score2 = getG.nextInt();
maxScore2 = getG.nextInt();


System.out.println("Total Points =" + (score1+ discussionGrade) + "/ "(maxScore1 + 20));

}



public static int getHwGrades()//method for asking and storing hw grades
{
int score1;
int maxScore1;
int nOfA;
Scanner getG = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("How many HW assignments are there?");
nOfA = getG.nextInt();

 for (int i = 1; i <= nOfA; i++) //loop that asks for the grades corresponding to the amount of hw assignments there were
 {
 System.out.println("What is your grade and then the max grade for assignment " + i + "?");
 score1 += getG.nextInt();
 maxScore1 += getG.nextInt();
 }

 return new getHwGrade(score1, maxScore1); //returns results of inputs into method holding the 2 variables
}



public static int numberSections() //finds out how many sections the student attended
{
Scanner getG = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("How many sections did you attend?");
return getG.nextInt();
}

public static int calcDGrade(int sections) //method to calculate the grade for the students sections
{
int maxDGrade = ((sections*4)); if (maxDGrade > 20) //limits total score to 20

{
   return 20;
} 
else 
{ 
return maxDGrade;
}

}



public static int getWeight(int weight1, int weight2)//returns the weight that will be used for weight3
{
   return (100-(weight1 + weight2));

}

public static double round2(double number) 
{
return Math.round(number * 100.0) / 100.0;
}



}
```

Comment: Please put more effort into formatting your code. Your code isn't indented consistently, you've got `if` statements *following* other statements on the same line, multiple blank lines for no obvious, and more code than I suspect you really need to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: AFAIK a method can return only one value, so the best I could advise is Concat both values with a separator and split them later

Comment: What do you expect `return new getHwGrade` to do, btw? You don't have a class called `getHwGrade` as far as I can see...

Comment: sorry, I had problems trying to get it to all show up in the code block so I had to keep messing wit it. And I'm using jGrasp

Comment: Are you allowed to use other classes?  I think that you're on the right track with `return new getHwGrade(score1, maxScore1);`, but of course you can't create an instance of a method.

Comment: I think so. I'm trying to return that method because I saw something similar when I was looking up an answer, and it seems like the right thing to do, but I got confused.

Answer (score 2):

Since you can only return a single value, you need to return a single value. :-) Normally if a method needs to return complex information, the way you have it do that is either:

1. Return a newly-created instance of a class that has fields for the individual pieces of information
2. Have the method fill in an instance of such a class that's passed to it (usually not ideal barring a good reason for doing it)

So for instance:

```
class HwGrades {
    private int score1;

    private int maxScore1;

    ScoreInfo(int _score1, int _maxScore1) {
        this.score1 = _score1;
        this.maxScore1 = _maxScore1;
    }

    // ...accessors as appropriate, presumably at least getters...
}
```

Then return an instance of `HwGrades` from `getHwGrades`:

```
public static int getHwGrades()//method for asking and storing hw grades
{
    int score1;
    int maxScore1;
    // ...
    return new HwGrades(score1, maxScore1);
}
```

---

If you needed, you could further decouple things by making `HwGrades` an *interface*, which you then implement with a private class, so that the API isn't tied to a specific class. Almost certainly overkill for a small school project.

Comment: so I need to create a getHwGrades class with this info? and the return new  getHwGrades line is correct then?

Comment: @dlnhnh: Don't call it `getHwGrades`, that looks like a method name. But yes, you'd create a class, perhaps `HwGrades`, and then `return new HwGrades(score1, maxScore1);` I've updated the answer to show doing that.

Comment: Why do you declare private ints in the class?

Comment: @dlnhnh: Default to encapsulation barring a good reason to do something else. :-) In any decent IDE, it's not more work (e.g., you can have the IDE generate the accessors), and it means you can do things like make `HwGrades` immutable.

Answer (score -3):

getHwGrade is expected to be a class.
Have a class like this

```
class getHwGrade{
int a;
int b;
public getHwGrade(int a,b){
this.a=a;this.b=b;
}
```